# How do I call fetchSignInMethodsForEmail() from Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, polymerfire

I have a PSK (Polymer Starter Kit) PWA build with polymerfire, I want to call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail()` from Firebase Auth. I have tried the following but with error.

```js
firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email).then((methods) => {
  // Do something
});
```

with the error `Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth(...).fetchSignInMethodsForEmail is not a function`.

I have tried the following as well with no luck, i.e.

```js
firebase.auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
firebase.$.auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email); // Assume firebase-auth with id of 'auth'
```

Comment: I don't immediately see what's wrong here. What version of the Firebase Authentication SDK are you using?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am using polymerfire v2.2.1 with firebase v4.4.0. Do note that when using the function, the user was not signed in as I am trying to link user account when user encounter  `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential` error.

Comment: I think I found the problem, need to use firebase v4.12.0 and above for the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail()` to work. Thanks for the hint. But I also saw that the method was depreciated in firebase v5.0.0, how should I go about it?

Comment: Where did you see that it is deprecated? I don't see that in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: "**Deprecated** `signInWithCredential`, `linkWithCredential`, `reauthenticateWithCredential` and **`fetchProvidersForEmail`** **in favor of** `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`, `linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`, `reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` and **`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`**". Emphasis mine.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the pointer, there's a lot of words and I actually missed that.

Answer (score 3):

For people using the new modular version it's done like this:

```
import {  fetchSignInMethodsForEmail } from 'firebase/auth';

    fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, email).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`fetchProvidersForEmail()` was introduced in Firebase JavaScript SDK v4.12 so you need to have at least v4.12 and above.

Being said that it is deprecated in v5.0 in favor of `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail()`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to declare Auth object.

```
 FirebaseAuth f = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Then call the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(), method.

as follows:

```
 // [START auth_differentiate_link]

auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {
    @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                  SignInMethodQueryResult result = task.getResult();
                  List<String> signInMethods = result.getSignInMethods();
           if(signInMethods.contains(EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD)) 
                {
                   // User can sign in with email/password
                } else if (signInMethods.contains(EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD)) {
                  // User can sign in with email/link
                }
               } else {
                  Log.e(TAG, "Error getting sign in methods for user", task.getException());
               }
           }
        });
  // [END auth_differentiate_link]
}
```